# Bookmarking shiny DT table Search Builder Extension input

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am looking for a way to use the shiny bookmarking feature with the shiny DT package and the search builder extension. The idea would be to be able to bookmark custom search builder parameters (along with other stuff from the app as needed) set by the user so they do not have keep entering every time they load the app.

Thanks,

Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible with the Shiny bookmarking feature. But here is a way to save the search query to a JSON file by clicking a button, and then it is possible to upload this file to rebuild the query.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

js <- c(
  "$('#save').on('click', function() {",
  "  var query = table.searchBuilder.getDetails();",
  "  var json = JSON.stringify(query, null, '\t');",
  "  var a = document.createElement('a');",
  "  var file = new Blob([json], {type: 'text/plain'});",
  "  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);",
  "  a.download = 'query.json';",
  "  a.click();",
  "});",
  "$('#upload').on('change', function(e) {",
  "  var reader = new FileReader();",
  "  reader.onload = function(event) {;",
  "    var query = JSON.parse(event.target.result);",
  "    table.searchBuilder.rebuild(query);",
  "  }",
  "  reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);",
  "});"
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  actionButton("save", "Save query", class = "btn-primary"),
  br(),
  tags$label(`for` = "upload", "Upload query"),
  tags$input(
    id = "upload", type = "file", accept = "application/json"
  ),
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$dtable <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris,
      extensions = c("SearchBuilder", "DateTime"),
      options = list(
        dom = "Qlfrtip",
        searchBuilder = TRUE
      ),
      callback = JS(js)
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: ohh, this is a cool idea! Thanks!